# ActiveRecord associations: am I doing it right?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on building a simple Rails application (this is my first rails project) for tracking statistics for users within a group. I've created the tables using a migration script and everything looks alright when I look at it in MySql, but not all of my models return data when I join them into another table.

Does anyone see anything wrong with my models, migration script, or data model?

Here is my migration file script code:

```
class CreateGroupsUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    create_table :types do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.belongs_to :type, index: true
    end

    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :email
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :e_password
      t.string :salt
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :groups_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :group, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :role, index: true
    end

    create_table :statistics do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :groups_users_statistics, id: false do |t|
      t.string :value
      t.belongs_to :group, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :statistic, index: true
    end

  end
end
```

Here are my my models:

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
    has_one :roles, through: :groups_users
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_one :types
end

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
    //i'm not too sure how to define this model
end
```

and here's my data model

[image: Here's my data model]

Comment: I think you should try to avoid `has_and_belongs_to_many` in favor of `has_many through`

Comment: You have `has_many :groups` in `type` model and you have `has_one :types`  in `group` model which is wrong and won't work.

Comment: @Pavan what would you recommend using instead?

Comment: You should change `has_one :types` to `belongs_to :type`.

Comment: @Esse if I use has_many through, do I need to define a model for the intersection tables?

Comment: Yes, define the GroupUser model.  Then User has_many :group_users, has_many :groups, through :group_users.  Depending on your needs, the GroupUser model might also be a better place to associate the GroupUserStatistic model (and this is one of the reasons to favor has_many ... through over has_and_belongs_to_many).

Answer (score 0):

I updated my models as per Esse, Pavan and AndyV's comments. Everything seems to be working fine now

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_users
    has_many :groups, through: :group_users

    has_many :group_user_statistics
    has_many :groups, through: :group_user_statistics
    has_many :statistics, through: :group_user_statistics
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_users
    has_many :users, through: :group_users

    has_many :group_user_statistics
    has_many :users, through: :group_user_statistics
    has_many :statistics, through: :group_user_statistics
end

class GroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :user
end

class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :group_user_statistics
    has_many :groups, through: :group_user_statistics
    has_many :users, through: :group_user_statistics
end

class GroupUserStatistic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
    belongs_to :statistic
end
```